# Using LSTM after CNN / Convolutional LSTM in keras

Tags: python, time-series, keras, lstm

I want to predict numerical Y variable using time-series image data. 
My dataset has these dimensions:

- X: (7000, 3, 128, 128)
- Y: (7000, 1)

7000 is the number of samples, each sample is 128 x 128 image and 3 is the number of channels (RGB). The range of the Y variable is 0-1.

Therefore, I want to apply an LSTM model after a CNN. But if I feed the CNN features to LSTM, so many errors occurs. Please help me.

This is my code:

```
size = 128
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, size, size)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))


#### LSTM #####
model.add(LSTM(50)) ???????????????????????????

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer= 'adam')
return model
```

Comment: You have the wrong column order for your X. The default order for Keras Conv2D is (samples, rows, cols, channels). If you want to use the order (samples, channels, rows, cols), you either need to reorder your X or use the argument "data_format = channels_first" for Conv2D.

Comment: Do you want to treat the features as timesteps?

Comment: @sladomic I find it. Thank you very much ;-)

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Maybe...? I want to feed the result features of CNN to LSTM.

Comment: But an image has a 2d nature, whereas sequences - a 1d one. What's the purpose of your application?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko My purpose is prediction of the continuous values(time-series) using image data. First, I want to analyze the image data using CNN, and then predict the continuous Y value by using the CNN model output as input to the LSTM.

Comment: Did @sladomic suggestion work?